# Conditionally append attribute to model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, append

Is it possible to append an attribute to my model whenever a model scope is called?

For example in my controller I want to call a scope to append those dynamic attribute like :

```
$Media_query = OutDoorMedia::query();
$Media_query->orderby('created_at', 'desc');
$Media_query->PreviouslyOrdered();
$Media = $Media_query->get();
```

And in my model I want to do something like :

```
class OutDoorMedia extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'address',
        'location',
        'media_type',
    ];
}

class scopePreviouslyOrdered extends OutDoorMedia
{
public $appends = ['previously_ordered'];

public function getPreviouslyOrderedAttribute()
{
    if ($this->hasMany('App\Models\OutDoorMediaOrders', 'odm_id', 'id')->Where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', MEDIA_ORDER_CHECKOUT_STATUS)
            ->orWhere('status', STATUS_TO_PAY);
    })->exists()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

But it's not working and I know it's wrong, How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding on how scopes should work. A scope is basically like a shortcut query for a model. You are using it to test existance of a relationship but there's a better way to do that using `whereHas`

Here's how you would achieve this using a relationship:

```
class OutDoorMedia extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'address',
        'location',
        'media_type',
    ];

    public function previousOrders() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OutDoorMediaOrders', 'odm_id', 'id');
    }
    public function getPreviouslyOrderedAttribute() {
        return $this->previousOrders()->exists(); 
    }
}
```

Then you simply do:

```
$Media_query = OutDoorMedia::whereHas('previousOrders')
                ->orderby('created_at', 'desc');
```

If you what the dynamic attribute appended on the model automatically you can just add the following to the model:

```
 public $appends = [ 'previously_ordered' ];
```

I guess if you want the best from both worlds you can do:

```
class OutdoorMediaWithPreviouslyOrdered extends OutDoorMedia {
     public $appends = [ 'previously_ordered' ];         
 }
```

Then when you need the appending model you can use :

```
 $Media_query = OutdoorMediaWithPreviouslyOrdered ::orderby('created_at', 'desc');
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think I got confused. but still there is a problem, I want to return all records and those which has relation to orders have parameter  previously_ordered = true and those that doesn't have any order then previously_ordered = false and I don't want to to be global, I want to attach it to my query in some controllers. that's why I thought scope will solve my problem

Comment: Right now with your approach the query return only those which have orders.

Comment: If you don't include the `whereHas` you get everything and then if you add the attribute code you should get the boolean `previously_ordered` on the model

Comment: the problem is how to add attribute code to the query! should I write another method for it in model?

Comment: What do you mean? If the attribute is in the `$appends` property then you shouldn't need to do anything to add it to the model. It will be automatically appended.

Comment: we returned to the first place, that's the problem, I need to append that attribute only in this controller, not all controllers which use above model. that's why I asked for scopes.

Comment: If you don't add it to the `$appends` and just access it when you need it like `$model->previously_ordered` it should just work, however it will not be added to JSON responses automatically

Comment: you mean to put: $model->previously_ordered  inside my controller query? if so how to assign it to each record properly? I don't want  to put foreach for this.

Comment: What are you doing with the records? You can use `->previously_ordered` on each model when you need to and it will work. However there's no way to mass assign it if you need to for example send all models as JSON (according to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/dynamic-append-on-model)) so I guess the answer is there's no silver  bullet. EIther use `$appends` to do it everywhere or if you just need it in certain JSON just loop to add it. As I noted in the update, extending the class should be an option as above.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and it's a good solution, but it's not what I was looking for, there is a problem with your solution which is the main query which I have above in the question may not be simple like this and has some conditions, and I don't want to use foreach loop to append that attribute, I wanted to append the attribute conditionally and where I needed. of course foreach loop does the job, or extending class, but I think would be a bit overhead to what I wanted to do. you can see my answer and figure out what i meant.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem with help of @apokryfos but with a bit tweak. hope this reduce wasting others time.

Instead of appending attributes on the model I have appended the said attribute to my model by the eloquent magic method :

```
$Media_query = OutDoorMedia::query();
$Media_query->orderby('created_at', 'desc');
$Media = $Media_query->get()->each(function ($items) {
          $items->append('previously_ordered');//add this attribute to all records which has the condition
         });
```

In Model As apokryfos said I have put these two methods:

```
  public function PreviousOrders() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OutDoorMediaOrders', 'odm_id', 'id');
  }

  public function getPreviouslyOrderedAttribute() {
      return $this->PreviousOrders()->exists();
  }
```

But I don't need this method and I had to remove it from the model because if it exist in model it will automatically append to model:

```
public $appends = [ 'previously_ordered' ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need to include in your response,

```
$data = FarmerQuestion::where([])->get();
$data->append(
    [
        'user_text',
        'user_photo',
        'district_text',
        'answers_count'
    ]
);
```